# Sessions being lost between Non SSL and SSL

Tags: php, session, ssl, https

I use PHP sessions on a website to store the ID of each customers basket but I've had a few customers report that when they add items to their basket and proceed to checkout and therefore switching to HTTPS, an error is displayed saying no items are present. However when they return to the main site (HTTP) - their items are back in the basket. So there must be something to do with the session now carrying over to HTTPS occasionally.

This has happened for only a handful of customers where the vast majority have absolutely no issues.

Any help would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: This could be specifics of their client (web browser). So the first thing to check is what browser(s) they use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webserver isn't forcing different urls for HTTPS and HTTP. Like with "www." on HTTPS, but not on HTTP.

"www.site.com" is not the same domain as "site.com".